# iAd Banner View

Tags: iad

So if I just added an iAd banner view (dragged it in to the xib file) and I already had a contract up and running, would it work as a normal iAd view? I saw some code that did it, but mine seemed to work. It looked like it had connected because it said "Test Advertisement" in the banner

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing a test advertisement that means it is working.

However, you still should follow Apple's iAd test [checklist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH6-SW1) to make sure it is properly working in all required situations to avoid a rejection.